# GIMP failed to load a large gif

Tags: gimp, software-recommendation, gif, video, animated-gif

The software GIMP failed to load large gif. When I loaded the gif in GIMP, most of the frames became transparent/nothing.

The number of frames is 1905

What happened? How can I fix this?

I am using a Windows 10 laptop.

By the way, this below is the link to the video:

https://youtu.be/gOSyI2B2YZs

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Your frames are in "combine" mode, so the most likely explanation is that your GIF is "optimized": a frame only contains the pixels that are different from those in the previous frame, and everything else in the frame is transparent. You can restore complete frames (if fact you must, if you intend to edit anything) using `Filters ➤ Animation ➤ Unoptimize`. You can later re-optimize the GIF using `Filters ➤ Animation ➤ Optimize (for GIF)` before exporting your final result.

Caveat: your image is large and you have many frames, so expect long processing times and intense disk activity unless you have a lot of RAM. To make sure that Gimp uses as much RAM as possible, see `Edit ➤ Preferences ➤ System resources ➤ Resource consumption ➤ Tile cache size` and set it to your RAM size minus your floor RAM usage (OS+base apps).